# modeling a real life scenerio in java

Tags: java

I have some doubt in design for following scenerio:
There is one Company.
Typical Company has at least the following attributes: (
 1. Name of company
 2. List of employees

Typical Employee has the following attributes: 
 1. Name
 2. Department

Typical Department has at least the following attributes: 
 1. numberOfEmps
 2. description

Every department should maintain a count of number of employees for that department. So whenever an employee is added or removed, a count corresponding to employee’s department should be incremented or decremented respectively.

How can i model this using java classes?w

Answer (score 1):

Have following classes.

***Company***

```
String id; // Unique identifier for company.
String name; // Name of company
```

***Employee***

```
String id; // Unique identifier of employee.
String Name; // Name of employee
Department department; // Instance of Department to which this employee belongs.
Company company; // Instance of Company to which this employee belongs.
```

***Department***

```
String id; // Unique identifier of department.
long employeeCount; // Count of employees.
String description; // Description of department.

public setEmployeeCount(); // Method which searches through all Employee objects matching current department with its unique id.
```

> Note. The reverse mapping of Department and Employee is done to ensure that at no point of time, one of the classes keeps Employee objects in list. This could form a point of concern in case where the employee count grows to a large level.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bidirectional relationship between employee and department:

The employee knows his department, the the department knows the employees belonging to it.

If the departement of the employee is changed and the new department is different from the current department the employee is removed from the current department (if the current department is not null), added to the new department and the current department is updated.

When an employee is added to a department, the department of the employee is changed.